# How to map a Bitwise inner product in finite space to an inner product in a Hilbert space.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ over the finite field. For vectors $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$, we define the bitwise inner product $a\cdot b$ as follows:

$$a \cdot b = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i (\text{mod} 2),$$

where $a_i,b_i$ are the $i$-th bits of vectors $a$ and $b$, respectively. In other words, the bitwise inner product $a\cdot b$ represents the number of bits where both vectors $a$ and $b$ have a $1$.

My question is about the nature of a map $f$ to a Hilbert space:
$$ f: a \mapsto \left|{f(a)}\right>,$$
with the following properties:
$$\lvert \left\langle f(b) \middle| f(a) \right \rangle \rvert^2 =  \begin{cases} 0& \text{if } a\cdot b = 1,\\ 1& \text{if } a\cdot b =0. \end{cases}$$

What would such a map be, if the dimension of the Hilbert space is finite and denoted by $D$?
It's sufficient if the values of $\lvert \left\langle f(b) \middle| f(a)\right\rangle\rvert^2$ can be categorized based on the value of $a\cdot b$, with the difference in values being at least $1/\text{poly}(n)$.

Comment: For example, let $H$ be a Hadamard gate and $|a>$ be a $n$-qubit state embedded $a_i$ to each $i$-th qubit.
The inner product $|<b|H|a>|^2$ looks like to categorize, but the value $<b|H|a>$ is $\frac{(-1)^{a\cdot b}}{\sqrt{2^n}}$, and $|<b|H|a>|^2 = \frac{1}{2^n}.